# Render UI Bootstrap directive generated from custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying a pretty unusual approach of rendering a UI Bootstrap tab via AngularJS.
What I'm trying to do is:
**Custom directive -- (That creates a) --> UI Bootstrap Markup -- (That renders) --> A Tab**

I know that two directive shouldn't edit the same DOM node, so I used
- Priority attribute
- Terminal attribute

To allow my directive to be the first ones that are compiled and only then the Bootstrap directive should work on the DOM node.

My initial markup is something like:

```
<mytabcontainer>
    <mytab title="Tab">Content</mytab>
<mytabcontainer>
```

That will convert to this Bootstrap markup

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab">Content</tab>
</tabset>
```

I correctly transform the custom markup to the Bootstrap one, but it doesn't get correctly displayed.
Here is a Fiddle that shows my current progress: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/0be430w5/1/)

*Unfortunately this is the only approach I can use because of previous decisions so please don't just tell me to directly use Bootstrap markup*

Comment: Take a look at $compile (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to compile your manually created new HTML Markup.

Comment: I tried to manually $compile(element) in the link function and the current element gets correctly compiled but unfortunately the <replace></replace> doesn't get replaced, so I don't get the children of the element in my final output

Comment: I made a library for rendering bootstrap [here](https://github.com/donaldmorton/darwin) you might see if it help you